# Can I generate a boxplot without a dataset and only having the relevant values (median, quartiles, etc) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have calculated medians, lower/upper quartiles, minimum and maximum values as part of a separate application of mine and written those values to a file and I would like to construct boxplots using these specific values.

Is there a way using matplotlib (or seaborn) to manually specify each of these values instead of providing an array of data (I don't need outliers)? I've tried looking through the documentation and I haven't found anything particularly relevant, but I may have overlooked something.

Something like:

```
plt.boxplot(median=median_val, quartiles=(lower, upper), range=(min, max))
```

would be ideal. I'm also open to any web solutions too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a baked-in function in matplotlib--[`bxp`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html)--that let's you specify the calculated statistics rather than the raw data to calculate from, avoiding the need to create your own function.

You'll need to call it as a method from your `Axes` object rather than from `plt`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stats = [
    {'med': 5, 'q1': 2, 'q3': 6, 'whislo': 1, 'whishi': 8},
    {'med': 4, 'q1': 2, 'q3': 6, 'whislo': 1, 'whishi': 8}
]

_, ax = plt.subplots();
ax.bxp(stats, showfliers=False);
```

Importantly, your input needs to be a list of dictionaries, corresponding to a list of boxes (even if just 1) to draw.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)