# Seaborn equivalent of matplotlib bxp?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

As mentioned in  [Can I generate a boxplot without a dataset and only having the relevant values (median, quartiles, etc) in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033076/can-i-generate-a-boxplot-without-a-dataset-and-only-having-the-relevant-values), Matplotlib can generate boxplot only using the relevant values. Can seaborn also do this?

Comment: For a seaborn boxplot you need actual data.  You can call `sns.set()` to set some seaborn style and then call matplotlib functions for drawing. Seaborn is an additional interface to matplotlib.  You can use matplotlib to customize seaborn plots. And you can call certain seaborn functions to work with matplotlib (e.g. `sns.despine`, `sns.color_palette(.. as_cmap=True)`, ....).

Comment: Cool. Thanks @JohanC!

Comment: For a really simple boxplot, you could try `sns.boxplot(x=[minimum, q1, median, q3, maximum])`. Or `sns.boxplot(data=[[min1, q1_1, median_1, q3_1, max1], [min2, q1_2, median_2, q3_2, max2])`